# Extract refactoring Visual Studio 2019 without Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

Are there any plugins or visual studio extensions which provide the same or very similar functionality to that of resharper's "extract" right click context menu?

We are using VS2019 with roslynator and intellicode as the performance hit from resharper simply was too much and could not be resolved after months of back and forth with R# support.

This is the one function we really struggle to live without. Can anyone answer how to effectively and efficiently refactor without resharper?

Comment: Although its a worthy question, you are still asking for an library, tool, or offsite resource unfortunately... ps, yeah resharper is a hog.

Comment: We got software recommendation for soft request. [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Whats wrong with asking a worthy question? :)

Comment: That's why i haven't down voted you or voted to close :) someone else might though